# Bootstrap modal popup auto closing

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, popup, modal-dialog

My Bootstrap modal popup is working fine. But my problem is that, my popup is opening an `editProductImage.aspx` page for image editing.

When I click on server side upload event, the modal popup is closed and `editProductImage.aspx` is opened in new window.

I want that modal popup to close after I click on the `Close` button. It should not close when uploading the image through the modal popup.

Comment: ok please post your code here for more information

Answer (score 1):

You are using server side control. That will cause a post back and refresh the page, if you want to keep the modal up, try posting the data from client side, using Ajax.